# iPad OpenGL ES extremely slow glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE()

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, multisampling

I am using the OpenGL ES Analyzer. It shows that calls to glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE() take around 90% of running time. Is this typical, or do I have some inefficiencies in my code? Here's my draw code:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, sampleFramebuffer);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Draw Stuff . . . 

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, defaultFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, sampleFramebuffer);
glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();

const GLenum discard1[]  = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT};
glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, 2, discard1);
const GLenum discard2[]  = {GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT};
glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, 1, discard2);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
[[EAGLContext currentContext] presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

The scene is complex with over a million triangles rendered each frame. I thought that that my slow frame rate  (10 fps) would be due to the draw calls - not the multisampling. Any thoughts?

Comment: How many samples are you using?  Are you making a call like glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4,GL_RGB565_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight); ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 4 samples with internal format GL_RGBA8_OES.

Comment: Yeh, that's pushing a lot of data.  Makes sense.  Have you tried GL_RGB5_A1_OES or fewer samples?

Comment: Woah, busy times. I finally got back to this issue. Changing the format didn't help much, but did hurt the color quality. I am using 4 samples for each pixel, so I can't do any less.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on iPad, and especially if you are on Retina, multisampling can be very expensive, so its not a surprise to me.  I know on many of the graphics video cards they stopped boasting of their abilities to pump millions of polys because everyone figured out that it didn't matter how many tris you pushed, because your post processing and your shaders were really taking all your time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but 90% of 10 fps gives a total time for each call to glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE(), which others are obviously not experiencing, so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

This was a tricky issue. I can't say I got all the details correct with the changes I made, but I believe that I was getting conflicting information from OpenGL ES Analyzer and my own log info. My own logs were telling me that the time spent was in each separate call to glDrawElements(), suggesting that the number of triangles was the problem. I started using different VAOs depending on detail required and this helped a lot.